# Field access via magic method in PhpStorm Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, phpstorm

I execute the following query and get the object of `PartnerFilterOption` model:

```
$partnerFilterOption = PartnerFilterOption::find()
    ->where(['=', 'ad_filter_option_id', $filterOptionId])
    ->andWhere(['=', 'ad_partner_filter_id', $partnerFilter['id']])
    ->one();
```

But if I try to get the model attribute, for example:

```
$value = $partnerFilterOption->mapping_value;
```

I get an error in PhpStorm.

Comment: @MuhmmadOmerAslam

Comment: There is a great Yii2 plugin for PhpStorm, just go to settings, plugins and search for Yii2 Support plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHPStorm doesn't know what data type is contained `$partnerFilterOption` variable. You should inform PHPStorm this information with help PHPDoc comment

```
/**
 * @var PartnerFilterOption $partnerFilterOption
 */
$partnerFilterOption = PartnerFilterOption::find()
    ->where(['=', 'ad_filter_option_id', $filterOptionId])
    ->andWhere(['=', 'ad_partner_filter_id', $partnerFilter['id']])
    ->one();
```

P.S. Your query could be written more comfortable for reading

```
$partnerFilterOption = PartnerFilterOption::find()
    ->where([
         'ad_filter_option_id' => $filterOptionId,
         'ad_partner_filter_id' => $partnerFilter['id']
    ])->one();
```

Comment: the code working fine but phpStrom just show this error

Comment: if i put it $partnerFilterOption[] the error removed.but i dont want to decelare array

Answer (score 3):

In this case you may use [`findOne()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#findOne()-detail) - PhpStorm should figure out type of returned object:

```
$partnerFilterOption = PartnerFilterOption::findOne([
        'ad_filter_option_id' => $filterOptionId,
        'ad_partner_filter_id' => $partnerFilter['id'],
    ]);
```

For more complicated conditions, where you need to use `find()` and `one()`, you need to use typehint (`/* @var $partnerFilterOption PartnerFilterOption */`) as @MaximFedorov suggested.

Comment: Good suggestion using findOne so that it explicitly knows the object type, however given that it's the same as Model::find($id)->one(); shouldn't it be clever enough to realise it?

Comment: `findOne()` has `static` as return type, so IDE knows that return type is the same as called class - `MyModel::findOne()` will return `MyModel`. With `find($id)->one()` it is more complicated, since `find()` returns generic `ActiveQuery`, which return generic `ActiveRecord` in `one()`. You would need to create custom `MyModelActiveQuery` and adjust phpdoc for `MyModel::find()` and `MyModelActiveQuery::one()` in order to give IDE hints about specific types. It may be also handled by some plugin, but that would work only in this IDE with this specific plugin, so using phpdoc is more portable.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the detailed response.